# Exibindo apenas valores inteiros no eixo X em gráfico com matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Gostaria de exibir no eixo X apenas valores inteiros de K:  `k in range(20)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline    

X = [k for k in range(20)]
    y = rmse_val
    plt.plot(X,y,color='green' , marker='o', markersize=2, linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
```

No entanto, o gráfico acima ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que alterar para o eixo X exibir os valores inteiros de 1 a 19?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o plt.xticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline    

X = [k for k in range(20)]
y = rmse_val
plt.xticks(range(len(X)))
plt.plot(X,y,color='green' , marker='o', markersize=2, linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
```